# Achartengine axis overlap on the top and bottom

Tags: achartengine, pan

When I try to pan the line of the timechart the chart the line able to move under the axis x.
The left-right side works, the top-bottom doesn't.
I don't set axis parameters, i think it should work without any manual settings, like the other side..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of AChartEngine. I suggest you upgrade to the official 1.1.0 release or even to the version 1.2.0 which is currently under development.

Comment: Not really, Dan. I tried 1.1.0 nigtly 1.1 and 1.2 all of them have the  same bug